# Oracle Sql developer "IN" statement for long list

Tags: oracle

how do i write a query where the results match a set of invoice numbers? I am using oracle sql developer. I would create a new table and use a join as a filter but I don't have privileges to create a table. also, the list includes about 2000 invoice numbers so an IN statement won't work. (please forgive me if the answer is already here but I haven't been able to find it on my own.)

Comment: This is a duplicate.  You can see an answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/39862166/5174436.  Interestingly, the question there is itself marked as a duplicate, so I cannot close this as a duplicate of the question to which I have linked.  (The "original" non-duplicate question does not answer the OP's question in this case, since he cannot create a table).

Comment: @MatthewMcPeak - I saw that on second reading so I removed my comment.

Comment: Thanks very much. I'm new to this and tried to find answer on my own by entering "sql in statement long list" and didn't find the answer.  Either way, thank you - hopefully, will get better at finding existing answers soon.